# How to connect to classic Bluetooth devices using objected c and ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Does anyone know how to connect to a classic Bluetooth device?  I have investigated using core Bluetooth with the device i am looking to connect with and this does not seem to be applicable (it must not be a Bluetooth le device). I know it must be possible because the Manufacturer of the device have their own software which connects using Bluetooth. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can without getting a special license from Apple through their partner program.